# What is the purpose of %TCIDATA tags in a LaTeX document?

Tags: packages

I recently had to edit a LaTeX file which has had numerous maintainers in the last couple of years. The header contains a block of `%TCIDATA` tags:

```
%TCIDATA{OutputFilter=latex2.dll}
%TCIDATA{Version=5.00.0.2570}
%TCIDATA{Created=Thu Jul 15 15:10:55 1999}
%TCIDATA{LastRevised=Monday, October 02, 2006 18:14:51}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="GraphicsSave" CONTENT="32">}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="PrintViewPercent" CONTENT="100">}
%TCIDATA{<META NAME="SaveForMode" CONTENT="1">}
%TCIDATA{Language=American English}
```

What do these tags do? Who parses them?

I googled `tcidata` and `tcidata latex` but found no meaningful results.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My google is more informative than yours:

http://www.tug.org/tugboat/tb15-3/tb44stenerson.pdf

> Ths article presents a program that facilitates the creation of
>   customized LATEX style files. The user provides a style specification
>   and the style editor writes all the macros. Editing takes place in a
>   graphical user interface composed of windows, menus, and dialog boxes.
>   While the editor may be used in any LATEX environment, it is intended
>   primarily for use with **TCI Software Research's word processor
>   Scientific Word**.

Your lines are `LaTeX` comments. They seem to describe the history of the generated file (probably written when saved from Scientific Word many years ago). It's likely that nothing parses them.

Comment: That program was an extremely cunning trick from the Devil to cause hatred to spill over the world, undoubtedly.

Comment: Not only was your google more informative than mine. You were also much better at making sense of the result. Thanks!